# C++11 Generic function to compare difference between two times?

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I would like to write a generic function so that I can compare two timestamps (my own class, returns nanoseconds since epoch) with whatever std::chrono::duration value (seconds, milliseconds etc) I pass in, so something like:

```
template<typename PERIOD>
bool IsTimestampWithin(const MyTime t1, const MyTime t2, const rsInt64 units){
    return t2.Nanos() - t1.Nanos() < units;
}
```

However, I am uncertain how to create an `std::chrono` object from the number of nanoseconds my timestamp returns. Every example I could find was using system or high precision clock casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) any duration to [`std::chrono::nanoseconds`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Helper_types), then [use `.count()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count) to extract the nanosecond value.

```
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::nanoseconds;

template<typename R, typename P>
bool IsTimestampWithin(const MyTime t1, const MyTime t2, const duration<R, P>& units){
    return t2.Nanos() - t1.Nanos() < duration_cast<nanoseconds>(units).count();
}

// usage:

if (isTimestampWithin(previous, now, std::chrono::milliseconds(300))) {
    ...
}
```

If your `MyTime` can be converted to a `std::chrono::time_point` structure (from the same clock source), then you don't even need to care about duration_cast, you could simply write:

```
return t2.to_time_point() - t1.to_time_point() < units;
```